# Concurrence plot in Python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, multilabel-classification

Recently I came across a research paper where they have used concurrence plots in R mldr library to show the concurrence between different labels in a multilabel dataset. However I couldn't find any reference to same plots in Python.

Is there really no library for Concurrence plots in Python?

Concurrence Plot is produced by using `plot(emotions, type = "LC")` in R, where `emotions` is an `mldr` object

Concurrence plot

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of the type of plot you really want?  And maybe some links that explain "concurrence plots" in the way you need them? How is your data organized? Do you have some test code?

Comment: Did you look at [bokeh's chord diagrams](https://python-graph-gallery.com/231-chord-diagram-with-bokeh/)?

Comment: @JohanC I didn't know about Bokeh at all. Thanks for your help. Didn't know that these are actually chord diagrams.